# 404 issue with basic authentication

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-mvc-routing, basic-authentication

I am writing to seek help, in understanding where I may be going wrong in the following code below.  I am trying to login as trial user, but it gives a 401 error on the client end.  however, I tried debugging my repository and it lead me to the following fault in the code  below with a 404 status code error.

```
       ClaimRole user = repository.trial(credentials[0], credentials[1]);
       ClaimRole user2 = repository.full(credentials[0], credentials[1]);

            if (user == null || user2  == null)
        {
            var resp = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.NotFound)
            {
                Content = new StringContent(string.Format("access denied")),
            };

        }// this bracket is highlighted while debugging through which the local window shows 404 status code
         else
        {
           IPrincipal principal = new GenericPrincipal(new GenericIdentity(user.Username, BasicAuthResponseHeaderValue), new string[] { user.role });
            Thread.CurrentPrincipal = principal;
            HttpContext.Current.User = principal;
        }

        return base.SendAsync(request, cancellationToken);

    }
```

repository code:

```
public ClaimRole trial(string username, string password)
 {
    var query = (from s in db.subs
                join u in db.user on s.sUID equals u.uID
                where s.sExpiryDate >= DateTime.Now &&
                u.uUsername == username &&
                u.uPassword == password
                select u).FirstOrDefault();

    if (query != null)
    {
        // Build a user and add the appropriate Trial role
        return new ClaimRole { Username = query.uUsername, Password = query.uPassword, role = "Trial" };
    }
    else
    {
        // No user was found
        return null;
    }
}

public ClaimRole full(string username, string password)
{
    var query = (from s in db.subs
                join u in db.user on s.sUID equals u.uID
                where s.sPID.Value == 163 &&
                u.uUsername == username &&
                u.uPassword == password
                select u).FirstOrDefault();

    if (query != null)
    {
        // Build a user and add the appropriate Trial role
        return new ClaimRole { Username = query.uUsername, Password = query.uPassword, role = "full" };
    }
    else
    {
        // No user was found
        return null;
    }
}
```

404 issue:

```
 resp --    {StatusCode: 404, ReasonPhrase: 'Not Found', Version: 1.1, Content: System.Net.Http.StringContent, Headers:
```

Values API controller:

```
 // [Authorize(Roles="full")]
   [Authorize]
    public IEnumerable<string> Get()
    {
        return new string[] { "value1", "value2" };
    }
```

UserDeTail Class:

```
    public UserDetail()
    {
        this.Subscription = new HashSet<Subscription>();
        this.Trial = new HashSet<Trial_Try>();
    }

    public int uID { get; set; }
    public string uUsername { get; set; }
    public string uPassword { get; set; }
    public string uOldPassword { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Subscription> Subscription { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Trial_Try> Trial { get; set; }
}
```

Updated repository queries (without the role) -- The issue still remain the same:

```
public UserDetail full(string username, string password)
    {
        var query = from s in db.Subscriptions
                    join u in db.UserDetails on s.sUID equals u.uID
                    where s.sPID.Value == 163 &&
                    u.uUsername == username &&
                    u.uPassword == password
                    select u;

        return query.FirstOrDefault();
    }

    public UserDetail trial(string username, string password)
    {
        var query = from s in db.Subscriptions
                    join u in db.UserDetails on s.sUID equals u.uID
                    where s.sExpiryDate >= DateTime.Now &&
                    u.uUsername == username &&
                    u.uPassword == password
                    select u;

        return query.FirstOrDefault();
    }
```

Updated Code:

```
        {
            ***IPrincipal principal = new GenericPrincipal(new GenericIdentity(user2.uUsername, user.uUsername, BasicAuthResponseHeaderValue), null);***
            Thread.CurrentPrincipal = principal;
            HttpContext.Current.User = principal;
        }
```

Could anyone please advice on solution or code, i need to look into.

Many thanks.

Comment: In debug you are seeing 404 because you are setting `resp` to NotFound. **BUT** Are you then returning  `resp` or are you later on in your code returning a 401? Show us your `return` statement which is the key here.

Comment: Hi, I have updated my code above with the return statement. Thank you for your reply.

Answer (score 1):

You are not using `resp` anywhere. You are setting it to 404 but never returning it or doing anything with it. It will therefore never be returned and your code will continue on and return 401.

So, after creating `resp` actually return it. Or, to tidy it up something like...

```
if (user == null || user2  == null)
{
    return new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.NotFound)
    {
        Content = new StringContent(string.Format("access denied")),
    };
}
//...
```

Comment: hi, Thank you for your response.  I have previously removed the 'var resp' code and used the ' return Unauthorized(request);' statement, which still causes a similar issue to, not being able to login as a trial user but only as full user by calling 'api/values'. Any advice.

Comment: Sorry, are you saying the issue is NOT that you want 404 instead of 401 but the REAL issue is that NO trial users can sign in where they should be able to?

Comment: yes that is correct.  I am sorry, I was little confused as the debugging output was throwing a 404 error on the client-end it was throwing a 401, so i was not sure what to look into.  Thank you for clarifying that.  I am using the values api controller to test the authentication method, but it is unable to differentiate between the  user role. is their something i need to change or look into. please advise, if possible. Many thanks.

Comment: Have you checked that the user you are trying to login as has an ExpiryDate later than today? If you comment out that line can you then sign in with Trial (i.e. `where s.sExpiryDate >= DateTime.Now &&` - obviously put the `where` on the next line?

Comment: I am testing trial users with expiryDate till 2015, sadly I am still experiencing the same issue.  I really appreciate your help and time into this. I have tried removing the where date clause and tried changing it couple of times, but sadly no luck. This is my original sql trial query  --- select u.[uID], u.[uUsername], u.[uPassword], s.[sExpiryDate]
from [dbo].[UserDetails] u
join [dbo].[Subscriptions] s
on u.uID = s.sUID
---where s.[sExpiryDate]>= getdate()
where  s.sPID = '163'.

Comment: But the only difference is the `WHERE` and the returning `role`. Have you stepped through and found if the `SELECT` is returning any records?

Comment: Hi, Thank you for your response back.  I have tried debugging it using   without the role property as well. The select is able to return the trial user details correctly, and pass it to user variable but then it  fails after that.  I have updated my code to show my entity class, for further reference, as I may have setup my entity framework UserDetail() class incorrectly for the query? if possible, any advice would be most welcomed.

Comment: I have also tested the trial and full queries separately (i.e UserDetail user = repository.trial(credentials[0], credentials[1]);) and I am able to login using the trial username and password but if combine the both queries, the trial one never executes.  Does this signifies that my method in the basic authenticate class is incorrect?

Comment: Hi, I am trying to add user2 to the generelIdentity, but it keeps throwing -- System.Security.Principal.GenericIdentity' does not contain a constructor that takes 3 arguments.  Is there a way to assign user2 variable to the identity.  Please advice, if possible.  Thank you for your time and help.

Comment: That is because `GenericIdentity` does NOT take 3 arguments... Maximum of two... Read here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.principal.genericidentity.aspx